# What is the word 'security value' means in AES encryption algorithm?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography

[image: This is my question]

I studied a lot trying to answer these three questions, but I still can't get it.

- In Question 1: I don't know what is the definition of  'security value' .
- In Question 2&3 : I can't see any security weaknesses in the scheme.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question.

Comment: I've also voted this down because you don't show anything you've done yourself; please ask a teacher or student assistant or re-read the literature you've no doubt received. A friendly hint: this scheme is close to but not quite CBC mode...

Answer (score 0):

The terminology is confusing, but normally we call that value the initial vector (IV).  The point of using a random IV is that if you encrypt the same message twice, then you do not get the same ciphertext twice, which is necessary to prevent leaking of information (for example, see what happens in [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29) -- look at the penguin images).

To the second question, a general security requirement is that even if the attacker supplies some number of inputs (`m_i`), he should not be able to figure out what other inputs are that he has no control over.  To understand why, look at padding oracle attacks such as [POODLE](https://www.openssl.org/~bodo/ssl-poodle.pdf).  If you understand POODLE, you should be able to come up with something similar on this proposed scheme.

Here's a hint on some problems that may happen.  Think about the case of `m_1 = m_2`.  Then what is `c_2`?  I'm not going to solve the homework for you, but that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Padding oracle attacks don't seem possible; the message has been defined as consisting of *t* 128 bit blocks. The more general plaintext oracle attacks could still work and obviously there is no protection of integrity or authenticity of the message. And then there is the XOR'ing of the not-quite-CBC scheme which jumps out.

Comment: Ahh, I think I see your point: this is technically not padding oracle attack because we are not getting errors about padding in the way the attack is implemented.  Okay, I agree.  However instead I'm imagining the same concept but instead of learning from padding errors, you learn from matching cipher texts.